# What can I do to fix this batch error when I'm adding to variables together?

Tags: batch-file

Every time I run the code below I get this error: `'10+1' is not recognized as an internal or operable program or batch file.` I have checked stack overflow and couldn't find anything. I apologize if this is a bad question.
This is the code:

```
`@echo off 
set chips=10
set return=1
echo %chips% chips remaining
echo choose a number between one and ten:
set /p num=number:
set /p yn=play? 
if %yn%==y (echo starting..) else (exit) 
timeout /t 3
SET /A test=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
echo %test%
if %test%==%num% (%chips%+%return%)
echo %chips% chips remaining`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if comparsion should be followed by recognized command, e.g. `set /a var=%chips%+%return%`, but is not in your example

`if %test%==%num% (%chips%+%return%)`